# Centering and aligning lines of HTML Text

Tags: html, css

I have a div with variable length lines of text in it. Right now I have something like

```
<div id="container" style="width: 500px">
  <div>Text Line 1</div>
  <div>Text Line 2 of different length</div>
  <div>Text Line 3</div>
</div>
```

I can `text-align: center` the container, but I want each line to be left justified relative to the longest line which is truly centered, as opposed to each line being centered on its own.

Is there an easy CSS way to do this... or should I resort to using tables to lay this out?

Answer (score 3):

Your html:

```
<div id="container">
  <span>
    <div>Text Line 1</div>
    <div>Text Line 2 of different length</div>
    <div>Text Line 3</div>
  </span>
</div>
```

​Your CSS:

```
#container {
  width: 500px;
  background: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

#container span {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#container span div {
  text-align: left;
}
​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/G6ABA/

Comment: Note: div inside span is not valid HTML, but using div does too http://jsfiddle.net/G6ABA/1/

Comment: The purpose is getting it to work in IE6. If you don't need IE6 support then yes, by all means use a div instead of a span.

Answer (score 0):

That should work:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 500px; text-align:center;">
  <div style="text-align:left;">
    <div>Text Line 1</div>
    <div>Text Line 2 of different length</div>
    <div>Text Line 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<span> </span>
```

and css

```
width:500px;
text-align:center;
position:absolute;
```

Answer (score 0):

do you set pic or color to div background?
or better i said is it your div width important?
if not maybe this solution can solve your problem:

```
<div id="someID" style="width: auto; text-align:left;">
 <div>line 1</div>
 <div>line 2 is more longer</div>
 <div>line 3</div>
</div>
```